# Is there a simple guide for how to set up a demo cloud?

Tags: cloud, uec, presentation

I would like to be able to demo a UEC cloud at a presentation. Is there a simple guide regarding the hardware I need, and how I need to configure the UEC in order to create a nice presentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the minimum requirements (for a one-machine setup) for setting up an Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud:

- **Machine**: at least 1 (though 2 or 3 is highly recommended, to separate controllers and nodes)
- **CPU**: +2Ghz (dual core recommended)
- **Memory**: +2Gb ram
- **Disk Space**: 100Gb

**Note that with those minimum specs, this will still be SLOW.**

You can find a **quick tutorial** located at: http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/private/deploy

As well, there is a **complete community guide** at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC